# Google App Script for Tag Manager Container List

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-tag-manager

I am running a google app script to get a list of containers for my GTM account. I have the follow piece of code:

```
TagManager.Accounts.Containers.list(parent)
```

parent = my GTM account ID, I even tried putting as a string, EG "xxxxx". I am sure the GTM account ID is correct.

The following error is returned:

> Uncaught Error: Response Code: 404. Message: Not Found.
>   at fetchContainers (Code:19)

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["Parent" is a path](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/api/v2/reference/accounts/containers/list):

[image: Screenshot of GTM documentation describing the parent argument]

Inserting just the ID will give an invalid path, and since the API client tries to retrieve a response from that path an invalid path will result in an error.

Comment: Thanks for that. Thought I was looking at the right documentation but I ended up looking at v1 not v2. Thanks for the link as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a call like this:

```
TagManager.Accounts.Containers.list(
    'accounts/' + accountId,
    {fields: 'container(name,publicId)'}
).container;
```

You can find a complete and working example here:

http://www.appsscript.it/tutorial/lista-dei-containers-di-google-tag-manager-in-spreadsheet-con-google-apps-script/